# Kali Linux на Virtual box не запускается

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, виртуальная-машина

Запускаю кали линукс на виртуал бокс , раньше не выдавало ошибок и работало нормально, сейчас при загрузке выдает такой экран и не дает пользоватся кали линуксом. Читал, что это просто уведомление, что в процессоре есть уязвимость, которое не должно препятствовать работе. Можно ли исправить? исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ловил что-то подобное, обычно помогала жесткая перезагрузка.

Если не помогает перезагрузка:

- Обратите внимание на загрузку ресурсов пк, возможно их не хватает для корректного запуска системы **<- скорее всего проблема тут**
- Если ресурсов более, чем достаточно - разбираться с параметрами запуска(конфигой виртуалбокса, если менялась), еще раз убедитесь в том, что с ресурсами системы все ок.

Если вы ничего не сломали в системе самостоятельно типа `chown` на корневую директорию - нужно копать в сторону загрузчика или виртуального диска

Comment: Непонятно, по какой логике умершая графика должна приводить к выпадению в initramfs

Comment: @andreymal справедливо, подправил ответ.